# How can I import a csv from another folder in python?

Tags: python, csv, import

I have a script in python, I want to import a csv from another folder. how can I do this? (for example, my .py is in a folder and I want to reach the data from the desktop)

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html
Also I recommend you to read about relative path and absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to understand how relative and absolute paths work.

I write an example using `relative paths`. I have two folders in desktop called `scripts` which includes python files and `csvs` which includes csv files. So, the code would be:

```
df = pd.read_csv('../csvs/file.csv)
```

The path means:

> `..` (previous folder, in this case, desktop folder).
>
> `/csvs` (csvs folder).
>
> `/file.csv` (the csv file).

Comment: edited; how could I read a file in the desktop?

Comment: Imagine the absolute path using Windows is 'C:\Users\Name\Desktop\scripts'.  '
'..' means the previous folder 'C:\Users\Name\Desktop'. Therefore, the correct form is pd.read_csv('../file.csv)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows:

- Right-click on the file on your desktop, and go to its properties.
- You should see a `Location:` tag that has a structure similar to this: `C:\Users\<user_name>\Desktop`
- Then you can define the file path as a variable in Python as:

```py
file_path = r'C:\Users\<your_user_name>\Desktop\<your_file_name>.csv'
```

- To read it:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
```

Obviously, always try to use relative paths instead of absolute paths like this in your code. Investing some time into learning the `Pathlib` module would greatly help you.